# ¿Migrar unas tablas en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Hola tengo una base de datos ya  creada con unas tablas y registros en ellas, esta base de datos fue previamente creada con laravel.

Ahora lo que pasa es que fue necesario modificar algunas relaciones entre las tablas desde las miagraciones de laravel y se agergaron nuevas tablas con relaciones a las que ya estaban.

Entonces quiero saber si se podria realizar la migracion de las nuevas tablas y la actualizacion de los nuevas relacion entre tablas sin que se borren los registros de las tablas que ya estan creadas.

por ejemplo

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+----------------------------+------------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name                       | email                        | telphone     | password | profesion_id | company_id | remember_token                                               | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------------------------+------------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Juan Carlos                | sdsdsdsds@sdsdsdsd.edu.co    | 573102184475 |          |            2 |          2 | NULL                                                         | 2017-05-18 16:22:39 | 2017-05-24 13:47:17 |
|  2 | JUan                       | juasdsd0@misdsdsda.edu.co    | NULL         |          |            1 |          1 | WkYYlmlZq4HVphmo1ZIcKMYd7WlYIliumg2ZqFhENzaJC3ccyJUIkap0KL2S | 2017-05-18 16:23:24 | 2017-05-18 16:23:24 |   
+----+----------------------------+------------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Tengo la tabla users que esta relacionada con la tabla roles la relacion es de muchos a muchos

```
+----+------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name | description   | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | adm  | Administrador | 2017-05-18 16:22:06 | 2017-05-18 16:22:06 |
|  2 | opr  | Operador      | 2017-05-18 16:22:06 | 2017-05-18 16:22:06 |
|  3 | usr  | Usuario       | 2017-05-18 16:22:06 | 2017-05-18 16:22:06 |
+----+------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

por eso existe esta otra tabla

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | rol_id | created_at | updated_at |
+----+---------+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |      3 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 |       2 |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 |       2 |      2 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  5 |       2 |      3 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  6 |       3 |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  8 |       5 |      3 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  9 |       4 |      1 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 10 |       6 |      3 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 11 |       7 |      3 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 12 |       8 |      3 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 13 |       9 |      3 | NULL       | NULL       |
| 14 |      10 |      3 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+---------+--------+------------+------------+
```

donde se relacionan los roles con los usuario

entonces ala migracion del usuario es esta

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('name',100);
            $table->string('email',191)->unique();
            $table->string('telphone', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->integer('profesion_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('profesion_id')->references('id')->on('profesion_cliente');
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

pero entonces los dos cambiso o acutalizacion que se va hacer es la siguient:

La migración debe quedar así

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('name',100);
            $table->string('email',191)->unique();
            $table->string('telphone', 12)->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->integer('profesion_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('profesion_id')->references('id')->on('profesion_cliente');                
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
                $table->integer('rol_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('rol_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Se agrego un nuevo campo y se elimino una relacion.

Entonces se quieren esos campos pero sin necesidad que se borren todos los registros de los usuarios.

Comment: ¿algún motivo particular por el cuál no fueron creadas dichas modificaciones a través de las migraciones de Laravel? No estoy seguro de entender lo que quieres hacer, tal vez puedes agregar un ejemplo.

Comment: @Shaz Ok se agrego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es crear una nueva migración, la generas por medio del comando típico: `php artisan make:migration agregar_campos_usuario`.

A continuación creas el esquema de la migración como de costumbre en su archivo respectivo, pero en vez de usar el método `create()`, utilizas `table()` para agregar o eliminar campos:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['company_id']);
    $table->dropColumn('company_id');

    $table->string('url')->nullable();
    $table->integer('rol_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('rol_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
});
```

Comment: Es decir con esta nueva migración se actualiza la tabla y se corro el comando php artisan migrate normal?

Comment: Sí, exacto, olvidé agregar el comando `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: Ahora  si en el futuro necesite otro cambio es necesario volver a crear una nueva migracion.

Comment: Exactamente, he estado en proyectos donde al final hay 30 o más archivos de migraciones. Pero es muy útil al momento que se necesite montar un proyecto y para las pruebas también.